Cannot use arrow keys with BASH / Konsole / sqlite
I'm having a problem with Bash / Konsole / sqlite. When I enter sqlite and hit the up arrow key I get
sqlite> ^[[A

If I su into another user from the same Konsole session all is OK.
I've looked at the environment variables and can see nothing that appears to be the error.
Any suggestions?
EDIT:
As requested
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color


There is something that has changed the key mapping in KDE itself. This can occur is a couple of places, but since this in konsole, it is likely a setting related to konsole itself. If you were not in kde, then /etc/inputrc or ~/.inputrc would be the likely places to look. I'm not familiar with the sqlite shell itself, but it also may contain a setting. This question is likely better for Unix & Linux.

Is is a documented feature that the up arrow should work? The old Sybase isql (for example) had no line editing features built it. That may be the case here.

@DavidC.Rankin: "if you were not in kde" doesn't really make sense, as inputrc is on the opposite side of KDE, not an alternative – KDE would be the input provider whereas Readline (inputrc) is the input consumer (i.e. it's what provides the line-editing for the sqlite shell in reaction to received keypresses)... Either way, the key mapping from KDE is correct, ESC [ A is the regular code for "up arrow" in konsole and other xterm-like terminals.

What the intent was is that KDE/konsole provides an additional layer of settings that can affect the key mappings. So I guess the way to put it is if you haven't messed with any of the run-control files read on system start, the likely place for the errant setting is in KDE and likely konsole settings themselves. (and I wouldn't put it past a KDE "oops" in the ~/.config directory either)

People, you seem to have missed my comment re ssh'ing to another user in the SAME Konsole session.

What is your terminal type set to?   check with echo $TERM and add that to your question.

I've looked at the environment variables and ... .. I would save the envs to separate files and diff them. set > set_use41.out ; su user2 ; set >set_user2.out : diff set_user1.out set_user2.out. Maybe something will be more obvious there. If that doesn't help then same with stty -a > stty_u...; su ; stty... ; diff .. Good luck.
